# VPS. Как настроить привязку с доменом?

Tags: php, debian, apache2, домен, vps

Первый раз использую VPS.

Возникла проблема с доменом. Установил apache2, php5, mysql.
Создал для теста виртуальный хост test.cc У себя на локальной машине прописал в hosts айпи своего сервера, чтобы он соответствовал test.cc

т.е. если я в браузере забиваю test.cc то должен открываться мой тестовый сайт на VPS, но он почему то не открывается. Что я упускаю? что нужно сделать, чтобы при обращение браузера к моему серверу на vps он открывал нужные сайты?

OS: Debian 8

Comment: а по ip открывает? что за хостс, на какой системе? браузер перезагрузить после изменения хостс или сбросить dns кеш браузер/ос? помогает, точно говорю. chrome://net-internals/#dns

Comment: Покажите как в http.conf прописали виртуальные хосты. Ну и да, вы ребутали апач после этого ?

Comment: Разобрался. Оказывается надо было в панели управления VPS у хостера добавить мой домен. ))

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Оказывается надо было в панели управления VPS у хостера добавить мой домен. ))

Comment: А что это за vps такой, что домен надо у хостера добавлять? Не попутали Вы его с обычным хостингом?

Comment: @Sergey скорее всего он имеет ввиду что-то вроде cpanel или isp

Comment: Хостинг Jino, обычный VPS за 500р